# Rails regex: validates_format_for date format with two different separators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I want to validate European date formats like `"10.02.2012"` or `"10-02-2012"` in my model.

Therefore I am using this line:

```
validates_format_of :matchdate, :with => /\A\d{2}(\.|-)\d{2}(\.|-)\d{4}\Z/i, :message => "Date incorrect"
```

The regex must be right, but whatever I type in, it always returns `"Date incorrect"`.

I get the input from a form where I use

```
<%= f.text_field :matchdate, :size => '10' %>
```

together with the Datepicker UI, that outputs the right format. (I want to use both "." and "-" seperators, cause I collect the date in another scope, where both versions should be allowed.)

The params look correct as well, there it says: `"...matchdate"=>"29.09.2012"`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try with /^\d{2}(\.|-)\d{2}(\.|-)\d{4}$/i ?

Comment: yes thanks, but it does not work as well.

Comment: this is worth a shot:
/\A[[:digit:]]{2}(\.|-)[[:digit:]]{2}(\.|-)[[:digit:]]{4}\Z/i

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you initiate new instance of your model from `params`, Rails casts your date into `Date` object (example using my own model):

```
i = Invoice.new due_date: "29.09.2012"
i.due_date                              #=> Sat, 29 Sep 2012 
i.due_date.class                        #=> Date
```

But you can't validate `Date` with a `Regex`. What you actually need is

```
validates :matchdate, presence: true
```

because it will be `nil` if Rails can't parse it, and maybe add some [custom validators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#validates-with) if needed.

Comment: Ah, thats the clue, thanks. In the meantime I declared a simple method that works aswell: `def format_date
  errors.add(:matchdate, 'Date wrong') if !matchdate.is_a?(Date)
end`